# How to identify HorizontalScrollview child is FULLY visible or not

Tags: android, horizontalscrollview

I have some buttons in `HorizontalScrollView` I want to display navigation arrow at both end of the `HorizontalScrollView`. If the child at 0 index is  fully visible then the Left Arrow should be invisible when user scroll left to right and child at 0 index is not visible then Left arrow display again same logic apply for the right side arrow.

I have tried below code:

```
private boolean isViewVisible(HorizontalScrollView hs, View view) {
        Rect scrollBounds = new Rect();
        hs.getHitRect(scrollBounds);
        if (!view.getLocalVisibleRect(scrollBounds)
            || scrollBounds.height() < view.getHeight()) {
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    }
```

It works fine and return true if the single pixels of view or partial view is visible.

Then I tried below code for FULLY visible but it works for `ScrollView` not for `HorizontalScrollView`

```
private boolean isViewVisible(View view) {
    Rect scrollBounds = new Rect();
    mScrollView.getDrawingRect(scrollBounds);

    float top = view.getY();
    float bottom = top + view.getHeight();

    if (scrollBounds.top < top && scrollBounds.bottom > bottom) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

I want to change the above code for `HorizontalScrollView`.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This question is from a few month ago so I assume you found your answer but maybe it will help someone else.

This worked for me:

```
private boolean isViewVisible(View view) {
    Rect scrollBounds = new Rect();
    yourHorizontalScrollView.getDrawingRect(scrollBounds);
    int rightEdge = view.getRight();
    int leftEdge = rightEdge - view.getWidth();
    int width = view.getWidth();
    if ((scrollBounds.right > (rightEdge + width) && scrollBounds.left < leftEdge)) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```